# How to use FileSystemWatcher in Windows service

Tags: .net, windows-services, filesystemwatcher

If I use FileSystemWatcher for monitoring files created on network share in console application, everything works fine. But if I move this simple code into Windows service, it does not work. I tried lot of various things: Checking access permissions of given folder, trying to run service as LocalService, LocalSystem, Network service and administrative domain user account. I also tried impersonation of code using SimpleImpersonation library. Nothing worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure you are not using mapped drive letters. Mapped drive letters are only available to users when logged in. The path should be specified as a UNC path for example:  \\server\share\subfolder\

Comment: Does the code in the service throw an exception, or does it just not receive any events?

Comment: @Wiz It just not receive any events. I also tried UNC paths without success. Network share is Samba share, but that should not be a problem, because it works in normal application (not service).

Comment: I just found that if I use Release version of service, it does not work. If I use Debug version, it works. I have no preprocessor directives used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in account, under which was service started. For FileSystemWatcher to correctly watch changes on Samba network share, I used Administrator account from domain.